# Eloquent: get average score by foreign model

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have three models:

- Product
- Review
- Score

They are linked like this:

- Product (hasMany) -> Review (hasOne) -> Score

Review model:

- text
- product_id
- score_id

Score model:

- value (number)

My relation in Product model:

```
public function reviews () {
  return $this->hasMany(Review::class, 'product_id', 'id');
}

public function averageScore () {
  // ???
}
```

I need to calculate average product score (by score.value prop), but have no idea how to achieve it.

Comment: If `reviews` table has `score_id` field then relation should be `belongsTo(Score::class)`. Otherwise, foreign key should be in `scores` table.

Comment: As an aside: Having a separate Score table to store a single numeric score looks a bit overkill to me. If you're doing it to ensure only valid scores are recorded you could use an [`enum`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html)

Comment: @apokryfos thank you, code in my post is just an examle. In real app it has more fields (and im using Enums for things you mentioned)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two routes you can go the pure `SQL` approach or you can use `Eloquent` to eager load it and calculate it. The last solution avoids N+1 problems the best but sometimes `SQL` only solutions can be beneficial, that you don't have to iterate over as many models.

**Eloquent solution**

```
// when fetching products
Product::with('reviews.score');


// In your product model
public function averageScore () {
    return $this->reviews->sum(function (Review $review) {
        $review->score->value;
    });
}
```

Here you have to iterate over most of the relationships, but everything is eager loaded. Doing this for multiple will produce minimal `SQL` queries.

**SQL solution**

```
public function averageScore () {
    return Score::whereIn('id', $this->reviews()->pluck('score_id'))
        ->sum('value');
}
```

If you iterate over this, it will create N queries. Is pretty efficient when only called once.

Comment: There is an approach for the SQL solution where you write it using an IN statement for a single query, i feel that is overcomplicating it for the scope of most projects.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this function by collection or by the query builder both

The collection approach is

```
public function averageScore(){
$reviews = $this->reviews;

$averageScore = $reviews->map(function ($review) {
    return $review->score->value;
})->avg();
return $averageScore ?? 0;
}
```

The query bilder approach is below

```
public function averageScore(){
$reviews = $this->reviews;

$averageScore = Review::where('product_id', $this->id)
    ->join('scores', 'reviews.score_id', '=', 'scores.id')
    ->avg('scores.value');
});
return $averageScore ?? 0;
}
```

However the query builder approach is more optimized. You may use one as per your use case.